# Borland StarTeam CP 2009 merge/compare tool bug?

Tags: starteam

I am using StarTeamCP Client 2009 build 11.0.0-58 on Linux.
I am having issues with StarTeam's file merge/compare utility.

When I launch the utility from StarTeam to compare/merge files, 
the progress bar on the bottom fill never finish (it flickers from right to left with "Finding Differences...") 
I can just link another application for normal merging/comparing, but when it is in the view comparison mode, it only allows StarTeam's compare tool to show the file differences.

Has anyone had similar issues?

Comment: starteam is a piece of $##$#. Its actually more expensive than clearcase. Its beyond me why my co wouldnt switch.

Answer (score 0):

Two things can help you solve this:

1. Take the **latest StarTeamCP Client** you can find and use it -
   those are backward-compatible for at least two versions of the server.
   Should also be able to get the latest patches from **Borland/MicroFocus**
   (they don't always make them available for download from their site).
2. Another thing to look for: **Java Heap-Size is Too Low on Linux** -
   On Linux/Unix, set parameters for the Java-VM before opening StarTeam:

   ```
   export options="-Xms256m -Xmx512m"
   ```

   After that, open the StarTeam Client as usual:

   ```
   StarTeam
   ```

   or

   ```
   /opt/StarTeam/bin/StarTeamCP &
   ```

   or

   ```
   /opt/StarTeamCP_2009/bin/StarTeamCP &
   ```

   (This parameter can also be configured in **StarTeamCP.lax** file,
   if you know what you are doing...)